# Como generar un campo para que el usuario capture una nueva contraseña

Tags: c#, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una aplicación web donde los usuarios, usan credenciales de ingreso con lo que el usuario y la contraseña quedan guardados. En otro modulo necesito que un usuario superior capture su password, pero el autocomplete no funciona y me muestra las contraseñas guardadas.

```html
Password: <input type="password" autocomplete="off">
Password: <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Estos no funcionan.

Ojala me puedan ayudar
gracias

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien tu problema, ¿podrías agregar mas información? tampoco entiendo la relación de la pregunta con las etiquetas.

Comment: Hola... los exploradores de ahora en los campos tipos password, dejan guardada la contraseña, si dentro de la aplicacion pongo otro campo de este tipo me va mostrar la contreseña del usuario logueado. lo que quiero es un usuario de un puesto superior pueda ingresar una contrseña en la aplicación, sin que ocurra esto.

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionar mi problema con este `plugin`:

https://terrylinooo.github.io/jquery.disableAutoFill/html5-form-validate.html

Ahora mi código quedo así:

```
var Preguntas;

    $(function () {


        Preguntas = new Array();


        $(".password").keypress(function (event) {
            //alert("El código de la tecla " + String.fromCharCode(event.which) + " es: " + event.which);
            //$("#escribe").val("");
            //$('.contra').val(String.fromCharCode(event.which));

            Preguntas.push((String.fromCharCode(event.which)));

            $('#login-form').disableAutoFill({


                passwordField: '.password',
                debugMode: false,
                randomizeInputName: true,
                html5FormValidate: true
            });

        });

        function checkForm() {
            form = document.getElementById('login-form');
            if (form.password.value == '') {
                alert('Cannot leave Password field blank.');
                form.password.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (form.username.value == '') {
                alert('Cannot leave User Id field blank.');
                form.username.focus();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }




    });
```

Espero les sirva, si les pasa un día.